# Storing data in an array and restricting it to numbers of similar value python

Tags: python

```
import array as arr
data3=data.resample('H').mean().round(1)
print(data3)
Ldata = 0
Hdata = 10

for i in range(7):
    data4 = ( data3['CO2'][i+1] - data3['CO2'][i] )
    
    if data4 < Hdata and data4 >Ldata :
        print(data4)
```

This gives me a table which i need but also the following figures.

```
0.39999999999997726
2.699999999999932
6.400000000000091
5.0
6.0
```

I need to store these figures in an array and then I need to extract the numbers which are closest together, in this case 5.0, 6.0 and 6.4 for use further on, while appending the rest? I've been stuck on this for quite some time, can anyone help?
I'm open to any method to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Closest together by what algoritm?

Comment: What I believe would work is the following. In my list of numbers I wish to take the integer which appears the most, in this case 6 appears twice, and then any other number which falls in the range of +0.25(6) and -0.25(6) I'd also like to save, this would also save 5.0 as 6.4-1.5 = 4.9.  while appending anything outside of that range.